# Get Facebook Comments via the Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im trying to get Facebook comments using the Graph Api.
I've researched online and found an example that works but there's one thing that about it that I can't find any information about it.

Here's the Example that works:

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_118464504835613/comments?access_token=ZZZZZZZ

https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/comments?access_token=ZZZZZZZ

How do I get XXXXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY ?
Is it the UserId concatenated with the Comment Id, is it returned by the Graph Api?

Why is there practicaly no information on this?

Comment: Yes, it is returned by the API, for example when you read a user’s or page’s  `/feed` connection.

Comment: XXXXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY is returned?

Comment: That's the value of the `id` field, yes. (Either for a post, or a specific comment, if you are reading those.)

Comment: CBroe, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of getting a page's post_id you can make a call like this to get the post_id.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{pageId}/posts?access_token={accessToken}
```

post_id looks something like this - 5704324444475_570454233326 and is in the id field of each returned post.

To get all comments for a page first you need to make a call to get all your posts and then make a call for each post to get comments.